# Reading output from netcat with bash

Tags: bash, ssh, fibonacci, netcat

I'm participating in a ctf where one task is to read a fibonacci number and calculate it very quick.

We are, via an already established ssh connection, to connect to a host. I type, "nc hostname port" in bash, and immediately the host returns "fib(n)". Calculating the fib number is ok, but how do I get bash to read the fib number and store it as a variable, calculate and then return the result to the host?

I'm thinking something in this direction:

```
#!/bin/bash

while read line # or line = $(nc hostname port) # ??
  fib = $(echo $line | tr -d -c 0-9) #Leaves only the number
  #Do calculation here. 
  #Return result to the server.
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: What's a "ctf"?

Comment: A "capture the flag" competition / contest.